# Decomposing vector space into direct sums

Tags: vector-spaces, direct-sum

I want to a find a vector space $V$ which has subspaces $W_1, W_2, W_3 \subset V$ so that $W_1 \neq W_2 \neq W_3$ and
$$W_2 \oplus W_3 = W_1 \oplus W_3.$$

One idea I had is:
\begin{align*}
V & = \mathbb{R}^2 \\
W_1 & = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid x \leq y \} \\
W_2 & = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid x \leq y  \} \\
W_3 & = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid x = y\}.
\end{align*}
I am struggling to prove that this satisfies $W_2 \oplus W_3 = W_1 \oplus W_3$. Any help on how to approach this problem would be helpful.

Comment: This can't work because your $W_1$ and $W_2$ are not linear subspaces.

Comment: Are there any restrictions? You could take $W_1=W_2=W_3$ for any vector space, for example.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I want $W_1 \neq W_2 \neq W _3$. Sorry. Let me edit the question.

Comment: When you define $W_1 \oplus W_2$, do you define this as $W_1 + W_2$ with the specification that $W_1 \cap W_2 = \{ 0 \}$? (Otherwise, with $A \oplus B = \{ (a, b ) : a \in A, b \in B \}$, and if $W_1 \cong W_2$, then there will be an isomorphism $W_1 \oplus W_3 \cong W_2 \oplus W_3$)

Answer (score 1):

If you allow $W_1 = W_2$, you can let $W_1$ and $W_3$ be any
linear subspaces of a vector space whose intersection is $\{0\}$.  If not, you can let $W_1$, $W_2$ and $W_3$ be any distinct one-dimensional subspaces of $\mathbb R^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Take $W_1 = \text{span}\{  (1, 1) \}$, $W_2 = \text{span} \{ (1, 0) \}$, and $W_3 = \text{span} \{ (0, 1) \}$. Then
$$W_1 \oplus W_3 = \mathbb{R}^2 = W_2 \oplus W_3$$